# Pay without paypal.com account

Tags: php

We are using PayPal Standard Website Payments method in osCommerce in a UK based site. We get this PayPal page on checkout.

http://screencast.com/t/5x3A5xUUG5

There is no option to pay if you don’t have a PayPal account.

The client sent this example and here it shows the option of paying without a PayPal account.
http://screencast.com/t/t4avCGae1ZXh

Please advise how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do Guest payment using paypal. As paypal mentioned in their help center, you can do. Please check below FAQ.

> **Do I need a PayPal account to pay for an eBay item?**
>
> No. You can use a credit card to pay for things on eBay if you don’t
>   have a PayPal account. As a PayPal guest you can use your credit card,
>   with guest checkout, up to 15 times to pay for things on eBay.  By
>   signing up for a PayPal account, though, you have more options when
>   you pay. You’ll be able to pay with your PayPal balance or — if that
>   isn’t enough to cover a payment — you can pay directly from your bank
>   account or use your debit or credit card.  Whatever payment method you
>   choose, your financial information is secure. Merchants get paid but
>   never see your bank account details or debit/credit card numbers.

Reference : [Link](https://www.paypal.com/helpcenter/main.jsp;jsessionid=JFDJ78H4dmQnw6PvjNHLk90Q4QKwkCfD4CYQvBrHhrQ2x5GxN2Tv!-7839025?t=solutionTab&ft=homeTab&ps=&solutionId=10133&locale=en_US&_dyncharset=UTF-8&countrycode=IE&cmd=_help&serverInstance=9004)

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on this by searching "pay as paypal guest" on google or other search engine.

To find specific information about implementing guest payment option, you have to check Paypal API.

This feature is available to Premier and Business account holders only. Source: [Buyers Can Checkout Without a PayPal Account](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/WAX_landing-outside)